# unable to start scrapyd in windows cmd

Tags: windows, cmd, scrapyd

I am trying to start scrapyd in windows cmd using `scrapyd`, however error below occurred.

```
C:\Users\Zheyuuu>scrapyd
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\anacaonda\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "d:\anacaonda\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "D:\Anacaonda\Scripts\scrapyd.exe\__main__.py", line 5, in <module>
  File "d:\anacaonda\lib\site-packages\scrapyd\scripts\scrapyd_run.py", line 3, in <module>
    from twisted.scripts.twistd import run
  File "d:\anacaonda\lib\site-packages\twisted\scripts\twistd.py", line 17, in <module>
    from twisted.scripts._twistw import ServerOptions, \
  File "d:\anacaonda\lib\site-packages\twisted\scripts\_twistw.py", line 8, in <module>
    from twisted.application import app, service, internet
  File "d:\anacaonda\lib\site-packages\twisted\application\internet.py", line 54, in <module>
    from automat import MethodicalMachine
  File "d:\anacaonda\lib\site-packages\automat\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from ._methodical import MethodicalMachine
  File "d:\anacaonda\lib\site-packages\automat\_methodical.py", line 34, in <module>
    @attr.s(frozen=True)
TypeError: attributes() got an unexpected keyword argument 'frozen'
```

I have been searching for solutions in google but unfortunatelly figure out why it happened. What's more, I have reinstalled **scrapyd** but it didn't work. My packages are below.

```
    Scrapy (1.3.3)
    scrapyd (1.2.0)
    scrapyd-client (1.1.0)
    Twisted (17.5.0) 
    Python: 3.6.1 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default, May 11 2017, 13:25:24) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I have solved it. The bug lies in Twisted. I reinstalled it and everything runs perfectly.